# Thesis by monograph, Must I publish my papers?

Tags: monograph

I am a Ph.D. student. My Ph.D. is by the monograph. I really do not exactly understand the requirements relative to the publication. That is, Must I publish all my papers. Or can I just write my thesis as a chapter with the result? Hence, I do not need to publish my chapters. I just would like to understand the requirement. I search in my uni, however, the information therein is not clear.

Comment: You're going to have to ask someone locally.  There aren't any universal rules on such things, and we have no way to know what your institution requires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will probably be closed because no one here can possibly know your institution's requirements. But, I'll take a stab at some general comments that apply to most institutions:

**Thesis by monograph** means writing a long "report" that your university approves.

**Thesis by publication** means stapling together a bunch of published papers.

In general, thus, if you are going for thesis by monograph, there is likely no requirement to publish. But, there are several good reasons to do so:

- Papers are very important for you if you want an academic career (or any career in research)
- Papers are very important for your advisor's and co-workers' academic careers. Indeed, I wouldn't be surprised if your advisor required/expected you to publish your good results
- Papers are useful to the field as a whole, as papers are much more widely-read than thesis monographs

I should also clarify that publishing a paper does not mean just submitting a chapter from your manuscript to a journal. This is not the forum to describe how to publish papers; your advisor should help you with this.

Comment: My supervisor told me that, it is not required to publish my papers before submitting my thesis. That is all.

Comment: This depends also on the university. For example, I have to write a monograph, nevertheless, my university requires me to publish at least one peer-reviewed paper and most professors expect at least 3 papers.

Comment: This also depends on the discipline. Some (e.g. history) mainly value manuscrips/books, others (e.g. economics) mainly value papers/articles. In some countries (e.g. Germany) you do need to publish the manuscript, but that usually covered by vanity publishers(who in that case have a legitimate role in academia).